# Configure argument class to use on development/production

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I've got class which should have different argument value on development and production mode. As far as I know I can use `facesconfig.xml` to pass params to `ManagedBeans` but I use annotations instead of *.xml config files and I don't want to mix those two solutions. What is the best solution to do this? I want to use built-in JavaEE/JSF mechanism instead of creating new config file. I would be grateful for suggestions.

My application uses JSF2/JPA and is deployed on OpenShift server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@ManagedProperty` annotation to get context parameters:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{initParam['javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE']}"
private String stage;

// getter and setter
```

Your `stage` field will have value `Development` or `Production` so use them according to your wishes.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to use it. Can you tell me what is the best solution to pass different params on production/development mode without necessity to recompile application (*.war)?

Comment: @pepuch You can add global resource (for example add in server.xml of tomcat) and read that property from JNDI (`initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/myvar")`). For your server consult its manual, I'm not familiar with OpenShift.